# Arduino LED matrix and 2D array, data seems to be corrupting

Tags: programming, led, arduino-nano

Duplicate of [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/102224/38392)

I'm trying to drive an 8x8 LED matrix with an arduino nano, but I can't get the LEDs to display what I tell it to.

I'm using [this](http://www.aliexpress.com/store/product/Free-shipping-10-pcs-8-8-3-75MM-Red-16P-dot-matrix-module-Dimensions-38-38/605870_879542981.html) LED Matrix

Here's my code:

```cpp
int row1 = 2;
int row2 = 3;
int row3 = 4;
int row4 = 5;
int row5 = 6;
int row6 = 7;
int row7 = 8;
int row8 = 9;

int col1 = 10;
int col2 = 11;
int col3 = 12;
int col4 = 18;
int col5 = 14;
int col6 = 15;
int col7 = 16;
int col8 = 17;

void setup() {
  int i;
  for(i = 2; i <= 18; i++) {
    pinMode(i,OUTPUT);
  }
  for(i = 2; i <= 9; i++) {
    digitalWrite(i, HIGH);
  }
}

void loop() {

  int display [8][8] = {
  {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
  {0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0},
  {0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0},
  {0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0},
  {0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0},
  {0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0},
  {0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0},
  {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1}
  };

  updateScreen(display);
}

void updateScreen(int screen[8][8]) {

  Serial.begin(9600);
  int i;
  for (i = row1; i <= row8; i++) {
    Serial.println(i-1); 
    digitalWrite(i, LOW);
      digitalWrite(col8, screen[i-2][0]);
      Serial.print(screen[i-2][0]); Serial.print("|"); 
      digitalWrite(col7, screen[i-2][1]);
      Serial.print(screen[i-2][1]); Serial.print("|"); 
      digitalWrite(col6, screen[i-2][2]);
      Serial.print(screen[i-2][2]); Serial.print("|"); 
      digitalWrite(col5, screen[i-2][3]);
      Serial.print(screen[i-2][3]); Serial.print("|"); 
      digitalWrite(col4, screen[i-2][4]);
      Serial.print(screen[i-2][4]); Serial.print("|"); 
      digitalWrite(col3, screen[i-2][5]);
      Serial.print(screen[i-2][5]); Serial.print("|"); 
      digitalWrite(col2, screen[i-2][6]);
      Serial.print(screen[i-2][6]); Serial.print("|"); 
      digitalWrite(col1, screen[i-2][7]);
      Serial.println(screen[i-2][7]);
      delay(1);
      blank();
    digitalWrite(i, HIGH);
  }

}

void blank() {
  digitalWrite(col1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(col2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(col3, LOW);
  digitalWrite(col4, LOW);
  digitalWrite(col5, LOW);
  digitalWrite(col6, LOW);
  digitalWrite(col7, LOW);
  digitalWrite(col8, LOW);
}
```

And here is the output:

```cpp
1 
1|0|0|0|0|0|0|0 
2 
0|1|0|0|0|0|0|0 
3 
0|0|1|0|0|0|0|0 
4 
0|0|0|1|0|0|0|0 
5 
0|0|0|0|1|0|0¾j 
6 
0|0|0|0|0|1|0|0 
7 
0|0|0|0|0|0|1|0 
8 
0|0|0|0|0|0|0|1
```

So I can tell that the error (probably) isn't my wiring, because those array values are clearly wrong, I have no idea where the `¾j` is coming from.

Comment: What do they display/what do you expect them to display?

Comment: Did you try a longer delay?

Comment: With that code as it is works fine, but if I try to display an alternating pattern of LEDs (i.e. like a chess board) like this:

{1,0.1,0,1,0,1,0},
{0.1,0,1,0,1,0,1},
{1,0.1,0,1,0,1,0},
{0.1,0,1,0,1,0,1},
{1,0.1,0,1,0,1,0},
{0.1,0,1,0,1,0,1},
{1,0.1,0,1,0,1,0},
{0.1,0,1,0,1,0,1}

Comment: @user168057 If you mean an alternating on-off pattern, then its displaying fine for me. Do you mean on the actual LEDs or only serial monitor?

Comment: Nevermind found the issue, I used a few `.` instead of `,` in my array declaration. Thanks anyways :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of my psychic abilities*, I am able to tell that you actually used `.` in a few places you should have used `,` in your array initialization. Replacing the `,`s with `.`s should fix the problem.

<sup><sup>*[Okay, okay, not really.](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/672/arduino-led-matrix-and-2d-array-data-seems-to-be-corrupting#comment1193_672)</sup></sup>

Answer (score 2):

Your initial problem can be sorted out by using a longer `delay`.

```
void updateScreen(int screen[8][8]) {

  Serial.begin(9600);
  int i;
  ........
      delay(100); //Longer time duration
      blank();
    digitalWrite(i, HIGH);
  }

}
```

As far as the chess pattern is concerned, it displays correctly for me.

```
void loop() {

  int display [8][8] = {
  {1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0},
  {0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1},
  {1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0},
  {0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1},
  {1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0},
  {0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1},
  {1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0},
  {0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1}
  };

  updateScreen(display);
}
```

Check your array declarations for errors.